# CoreData and FetchRequest, Issue with ForEach and "Cannot invoke initializer"

Tags: swiftui, ios13, xcode11

I just migrated to use CoreDate instead of a simple collection. I'm using iOS13 beta 8 and Xcode11 beta 6.

```
struct BeaconList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), animation: nil) var beacons: FetchedResults<Beacon>

    static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Beacon> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Beacon> = Beacon.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]

        return request
    }

    func buildView(name: String, beacons: [Beacon]) -> AnyView {
        return AnyView (
            Section(header: Text(name)) {
                ForEach(beacons) { beacon in
                    BeaconListEntry(beacon: beacon)
                }
            }
        )
    }

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                buildView(name: "MY BEACONS", beacons: beacons.filter { $0.isActive })
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Beacons")
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "antenna.radiowaves.left.and.right")
            Text("Beacons")
        }

    }
}
```

and with `BeaconListEntry`as follows:

```
struct BeaconListEntry : View {
   @Binding var beacon: Beacon

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(verbatim: beacon.name!)
        }
    }
}
```

(Please ignore the forced unwrapped, it's just for testing purposes)

When I used this with collections before I rewrote, it worked, but now I get the message

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ForEach<_, _, _>' with an argument list of type '([Beacon], @escaping (Binding<Beacon>) -> BeaconListEntry)'
```

and

```
1. Overloads for 'ForEach<_, _, _>' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Data, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content), (Range<Int>, content: @escaping (Int) -> Content)
```

Any idea on where to look? Is this the correct way to use `FetchedResults`?

Answer (score 0):

The `BeaconListEntry` initializer expects an argument having type `Binding`, so you should modify your call as follows:

```
BeaconListEntry(beacon: .constant(beacon))
```